# How to turn a pandas DataFrame column of lists into new rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like the following:

```
   info      number      names       
0  'boo'     10          ['John', 'Harry', 'Vincent']   
1  'far'     45          ['Andrea']        
2  'foo'     23          ['Juliet', 'Anna']
```

I would like to turn it into something like this:

```
f s  info      number      names       
0 0   'boo'     10         'John'
  1   'boo'     10         'Harry'
  2   'boo'     10         'Vincent'
1 0   'far'     45         'Andrea'       
2 0   'foo'     23         'Juliet'
  1   'foo'     23         'Anna'
```

Comment: Try numpy's meshgrid it grafts the data from one input to another.